# passing tableview outlet as an argument in cellForRowAtindexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am calling `cellForRowAtindexPath` manually in a `textFieldShouldReturn` from a view controller, and the arguments for  `cellForRowAtindexPath` are `tableViewOutlet` and `indexPath` ("index" in this example). Here both `cellForRowAtindexPath` and `tableViewOutlet` are from another view controller, I'm calling them by using instance.

Once `cellForRowAtindexPath` calling it showing error like:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    if(textField == carRating){
        let rating = Float(textField.text!)
        secondInstanceForMyData.masterCarData[index.row].carRating = rating
        let _: MyTableViewCell = myViewControllerInstance.tableView(myViewControllerInstance.tableViewWillLoad as UITableView, cellForRowAt: index) as! MyTableViewCell
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Means there is no data in variable from where we are fetching

Comment: What is the point of the line that starts with `let _: MyTableViewCell = ...` ?

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

What you're calling here is the tableview data source method `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAt:)`, which should never be called by you, it has to be implemented by you. Think of it this way, this method needs to provide a cell for the table view, not ask for it.

If you want to get a cell from an already populated tableview, call the tableview method `cellForRow(at:)`

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
if let cell = tableView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {
    // do something with the cell
}
```

And if you want to update your tableview, then you need to update your data source and either call `reloadData()` on your tableview or call one of the update methods.